# Real Time Services & Push Notification

Tags: push-notification, real-time, firebase, pusher

I am looking into building an app that has chat as one of its core components. Now I am looking into Real Time Services like Pusher, Firebase, Pubnub, etc.
While all these support real time messaging, I want a solution where I can send a message to the subscribed users and if the app isn't online (open), we fall back to Push Notification.

Is there any service that offers this? Or how do I go about achieving this? I would have gone for a traditional server approach but I need real time performance for chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PubNub do offer this functionality. In particular PubNub advertise "Seamless fallback to Push Notifications (Realtime socket connection attempted first)":
http://www.pubnub.com/how-it-works/mobile-push/

As do Realtime.co:
http://messaging-public.realtime.co/documentation/starting-guide/mobilepush.html